# unexpected output with group by

Tags: sql

Here is the DDL and DML:

```
create table fb_customers (
customer_id int,
customer_name varchar,
product_bought varchar);

insert into fb_customers values
(1, 'james', 'A'),(2, 'james', 'B'), (3, 'james', 'A'), (4, 'james', 'C'), (5, 'ada', 'A'), (6, 'ada', 'A'), (7, 'Tom', 'B'), (8, 'Leo', 'C');
```

when I select `customer_name` and `product_bought` with `group by`:

```
select customer_name, product_bought from fb_customers
group by customer_name, product_bought;
```

the result is surprisingly not grouped by name automatically - I thought with `group by` the result should be grouped by `customer_name` and `product_bought` but we can see `james` is separated and scattered instead of grouped together.
[image]

Now I'd like to find the customers who bought both `A` and `B`, and here is my query:

```
select customer_name from fb_customers
group by customer_name, product_bought
having sum(case when product_bought = 'A' then 1
                when product_bought = 'B' then 1
                else 0
           end) = 2;
```

and the result is surprising include `ada` who should not be there:

[image]

where am I wrong with these two questions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below - **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f16508802bffa75a8e765140d7ef5a05)** Here

```
select customer_name from fb_customers
where product_bought in ('A','B')
group by customer_name
having count(distinct product_bought)=2
```

Comment: Thanks @Fahmi for the quick solution! it works, but I still wonder what's my mistakes in my queries?

Comment: To be clear, the first solution works but not the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

please see the below photo 
you in your query writed for every  customer_name every where product_bought = 'A' then  +1 and every where  product_bought = 'B' then  +1 that in customer_name whit name's ada
ada A  +1
ada A  +1
since ada have tow 'A' that result sum in query is 2
**sum for ada=>1+1=2**
and see james
james   A   +1
james   B   +1
james   A   +1
james   C   0
since james have tow 'A' and one 'B' that result sum in query is 3
**sum for james=>1+1+1=3**
query result is ada since just sum ada is 2
[image]

and if you want use from your code you can edite as below

```
select customer_name from fb_customers
group by customer_name
having sum(case when product_bought = 'A' then 1
                else 0
           end) >= 1 
           and 
           sum(case when product_bought = 'B' then 1
                else 0
           end) >= 1
```